# How to count the digits of a number recursively in SML

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I need to count the digits of a number in a recursive way using Standard ML, assuming that the representation of the number 0 has 1 digit.

```
fun digitCount 0 = 1
  | digitCount n = 1 + digitCount (n div 10)
```

It would be easy to do if `countDigit(0)` was 0, but in the code that I wrote the result will always be added by one.

Comment: The two cases are "one-digit numbers" and "multiple-digit numbers", but you have the cases "zero" and "non-zero".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using `if then else` statement instead of pattern-matching on zero value?

```
fun digitCount n =
  if n < 10
  then 1
  else 1 + digitCount (n div 10)
```

It's not much more verbose than pattern-matching a can be even written as one-line:

```
fun digitCount n = if n < 10 then 1 else 1 + digitCount (n div 10)
```